# Is it possible to make a checkbox/radio button uncheckable?

Tags: android

The program I am making has several views in which the user is trying to basically figure out a lot of boolean values. Sounds strange, but what I mean is that my device will connect to another device via bluetooth, and then read the status of that device. I basically display a checklist of the current status of that device. So depending on what that device is doing, different checkboxes are checked. Is there a way to make all of the checkboxes unselectable?

Even better, is there a way to hardcode this into the XML file?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Have you considered using [`android:clickable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:clickable) for an xml attribute for your checkboxes?

From the documentation:

> Defines whether this view reacts to click events.

If it cannot react to click events, then it effectively becomes uncheckable.

Comment: what is the difference between android:clickable and android:enabled?

Comment: `clickable` is used to determine whether or not a click event should be sent to a `View`.  `enabled` is defined in `View`, but is left to be interpreted by its subclasses.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#isEnabled()

Comment: @JuiCe, if you use `RecyclerView` with `Checkbox`es and want to click `Checkbox`, check it and close `RecyclerView`, then `clickable=false` would be an appropriate option. If you use `enabled=false`, you won't click items.

Answer (score 14):

```
<CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/blahblah"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:enabled="false" />
```

**and in your code you can call `cbox.setChecked(boolean)`**

Comment: what is the difference between android:clickable and android:enabled?

Comment: It can be a wrong code. For instance, if you have a list of `Checkbox`es and want to close a screen when click on `Checkbox`, it won't react to a click (and won't close this screen). But when you set `android:clickable=false`, it will.

Answer (score 12):

to expand on what crocboy and nicholas.hauschild said.

Setting this in you XML

```
    android:enabled="false"
```

will make the button/checkbox be grayed-out, to show it is disabled

Another way to do this is to set it to:

```
    android:clickable="false"
```

Here is the code to make a RadioButton that is red, that turns green when checked (in your code), but can not be checked by the user.

```
    android:checked="false"
    android:textColor="#d1d2d4"
    android:buttonTint="#d1202d"
    android:textColorHighlight="#248d51"
    android:clickable="false"
```

AND here is the code to check it (this is using JSON: so it is checking if english=="yes")

```
    String yes = "yes";
    if(yourObject.english.equals(yes)) {
        if (m_english.isChecked()) {/*do nothing */}
        else m_english.toggle();
    }
```

Answer (score 10):

Check this out: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckBox.html

You can use `checkbox.setEnabled(false)` to make it unselectable.

Try this in your XML: `android:enabled="false"`

It's supposedly deprecated, but may work depending on your traget SDK.

Hope that helps!