# I have a radio group and in this radio group i have two radio buttons. how can i make Radio Button non-clickable in android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a radio group and in this radio group i have two radio buttons. I want make this radio button non-clickable for particular user. Please help me.

```
installation_Satisfactory=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.installation_satisfactory);

        if (roleID==19)
        {
            for(int i = 0;  i < installation_Satisfactory.getChildCount(); i++){
                ((RadioButton)installation_Satisfactory.getChildAt(i)).setEnabled(false);
        }


        }
```

I have tried this code and my role id is im using for particular user for that i want this radio button non-clickable. But if i'm not using role id it disabled for all users. but i want for particular user. Please help me

```
 if(Integer.parseInt(viewInspectionSheetModel.getInstallationSatisfactory())==1)


                            installation_Satisfactory.check(R.id.installation_yes);


                       if(Integer.parseInt(viewInspectionSheetModel.getInstallationSatisfactory())==0)
                            installation_Satisfactory.check(R.id.installation_no);
```

while i am using property setOnCheckedChangeListener (false) is showing error like can't use false in boolean. so please help me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213699/is-it-possible-to-make-a-checkbox-radio-button-uncheckable

Comment: you want to disable the radiogroup when userid matches to particular id, for example userid==19 ?

Answer (score 0):

Use both if and else for your case to solve your isssue.

```
if (roleID==19)
{
    for(int i = 0;  i < installation_Satisfactory.getChildCount(); i++){
        ((RadioButton)installation_Satisfactory.getChildAt(i)).setEnabled(false);
} else
{
    for(int i = 0;  i < installation_Satisfactory.getChildCount(); i++){
        ((RadioButton)installation_Satisfactory.getChildAt(i)).setEnabled(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
 radioButton1.setEnabled(false);
 radioButton2.setEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Add context around your answer for future learning purpose and downvote prevention. (From Review).

Answer (score 0):

int RoleID =19;
RadioGroup radioSexGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioSex);

```
        radioSexGroup.getChildCount();
        for(int i=0;i<radioSexGroup.getChildCount();i++)
        {
            RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton)radioSexGroup.getChildAt(i);
            if(RoleID==19)
            {
                if(radioButton.getId() == R.id.installation_satisfactory)
                {
                    radioButton.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
        }

xml :
<RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioSex"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/installation_satisfactory"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="male"
             />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioFemale"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="female" />

    </RadioGroup>
```